# How to restart a windows service using Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, service, scheduled-tasks

The easiest way to do this is to create a batch file with:

```
NET stop <service name>
NET start <service name>
```

Once the batch file is created and tested, add it to Windows Task Scheduler and run it at a specific time interval. Problem here is, when the bat file is missing or corrupt, the service won't restart. So, are there other ways to restart a service at a specific time interval?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Instead of using a bat file, you can simply create a Scheduled Task. Most of the time you define just one action. In this case, create two actions with the `NET` command. The first one to stop the service, the second one to start the service. Give them a `STOP` and `START` argument, followed by the service name.

In this example we restart the Printer Spooler service.

```
NET STOP "Print Spooler" 
NET START "Print Spooler"
```

[image]

[image]

Note: unfortunately `NET RESTART <service name>` does not exist.

Comment: Excellent tip!  Depending on the service, I sometimes add a `timeout /T 3` (where 3 is a # of seconds) in between the stop & start.

Comment: FYI the Service Name of "Print Spooler" is just "Spooler". "Print Spooler" is the Display Name.

Comment: @NateJ `timeout` appears to have no affect whatsoever.  I've tried intervals from 10 to as high as 120 and the restart is still instant.  I suspect it's run in parallel and the start is only sequential because it's queued by the service stopping.

Comment: Good tip @Kurt Van den Branden! And @NateJ your timeout tip likewise which worked for me on a Win2016 Server. I added `timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK` just for saftey sake.

Comment: You can also use a single action like `powershell -command "Restart-Service Spooler"`