# BizTalk2010 restart Receive location every hour

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

BizTalk2010 restart Receive location every 3 hour

we have a issue with third party sftp codeplex adapter 1.4 (receive location 'freeze' issue). There may be a fix in version 1.5 but for a short term solution is there a way to schedule a restart of one **Receive location** (Disable\enable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Task Scheduler to schedule a PowerShell that enables/disables your Receive Location.

Here https://biztalklive.blogspot.com.es/2017/10/powershell-script-to-enable-biztalk.html?m=1 you have a Script example and here how to schedule https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26747.windows-server-how-to-schedule-a-powershell-script-to-auto-run.aspx.

Comment: Thanks  works great. need one for send port - start stop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678243/biztalk210-powerscript-to-stop-and-start-send-port

Answer (score 0):

For a *temporary* solution, you can put that Receive Location in it's own Host Instance and use the Windows Scheduler to Stop and Start the Service periodically.

**You don't need any scripts or other complications, just the NET STOP/START commands.**

The setup is described in this other SO thread: [How to restart a windows service using Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309449/how-to-restart-a-windows-service-using-task-scheduler)

You can find the Service name in the Properties Services Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a powershell with the following script :

```
    #Get Receive locations
    [ARRAY]$ReceiveLocations = get-wmiobject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter {IsDisabled = "True" and (Name="Receive Location Name1" or Name="Receive Location Name2")}

    Foreach ($ReceiveLocation in $ReceiveLocations)
    {
        #EnableReceive locations
        $ReceiveLocation.InvokeMethod("Enable",$null)
    }
```

and create a windows task scheduler to execute the script